# How can I play a DVD-A (DVD-Audio) disc?

Tags: music, dvd-audio

I am able to play such a disc using VLC, but I am wondering if any music player supports the DVD-A format.

**Links:**

- [DVD-Audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Audio) - Wikipedia
- [Idea #22415: Please add full support for DVD-Audio and LPCM](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/22415) - Ubuntu Brainstorm

**Example DVD-A releases:**

- [Porcupine Tree - Fear Of A Blank Planet](http://www.burningshed.com/store/porcupinetree/product/169/639/)
- [Steven Wilson - Insurgentes](http://www.burningshed.com/store/stevenwilson/product/65/1391/)
- [King Crimson - In The Court Of The Crimson King (40th anniversary edition)](http://www.burningshed.com/store/kingcrimson/multiproduct/313/1658/)

**UPDATE:**

I checked Rhythmbox and Banshee - I found no option like *Play Disc* or *Open Disc*, so I have no idea how I could even try to start playing a DVD-A disc.
This has also nothing to do with missing plug-ins or codecs - the packages `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`, `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras` were installed on my machine before.

I guess I am stuck with VLC (Totem shows a DVD menu, but then hangs). However, **I am missing the regular music player experience** - ability to change order of tracks, adding tracks to a playlist, listening only to selected tracks, etc.

Comment: I'd suggest you install the `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` and `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` packages from the repository and then try in Rhythmbox, Totem (Movie Player) or Banshee.

Comment: Have you installed `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` ?

Comment: @fluteflute @karthick87 I updated my question.

Comment: Did anyone managed to burn DVD-Audio? I have asked this some time ago on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/146605/burn-24-96-flac-files-to-play-on-standalone-player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for rythembox and by extension gstreamer has not been written yet. Part of the problem as explained in this bug report is that the developer fears the decryption can't be cracked:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549184

But according to this bug report the decryption can be cracked using dvdcpxm's code:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549559

And this bug report further demonstrates that there is a way to play unencrypted super audio disks if only the developers would write the code:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549557

But the developer remarks he's never seen an Audio DVD. All in all it sounds like the developers don't really know what this format is, don't have access to it or don't have enough people demanding the support be added (or paying for it to be added).

My advice would be to create a comment in the bug 549557 above explaining and linking to bug 549559 anda link to vlc which does support the format. (mplayer might support it too)

Comment: I'd never heard of DVD-Audio before I saw this Question

Comment: @fluteflute - When you see a DVD with a VIDIO_TS directory, audio dvds are the other directory, the AUDIO_TS directory. That's why it's normally empty.

Comment: @fluteflute I edited my question and added a few example DVD-A releases.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it will play as a DVD in a DVD player like VLC or M player even if you get the right codecs installed, I used Audio Extraction, well to extract the 24 bit 96000Hz music files which can be played by Winamp which has support for 24/96000 5.1 Flac,

Though the problem with Ubuntu is that everything is downmixed to 44000Hz well this is the problem in Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: That's what I did, too - http://superuser.com/q/227712/341.